# Neo4j OGM - ineffective Filter.setRelationshipDirection()

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I try to load an entire object (with its hierarchy) with this code:

```
final Filter filter = new Filter (this.identity.name(),ComparisonOperator.EQUALS, identity);
filter.setRelationshipDirection(Relationship.OUTGOING);     
final Filters filters = new Filters (filter);
final Collection<T> values = ogmSession.loadAll(this.classType,filters , -1);
if (values != null){
    rvalue = values.iterator().next();
}
```

But the generated query is (with performance issue):

```
BoltRequest - Request: MATCH (n:`Procedure`) WHERE n.`name` = { `name_0` }  WITH n MATCH p=(n)-[*0..]-(m) RETURN p, ID(n) with params {name_0=WMS-1-B}
```

Instead of something like that (with relationship direction in last MATCH clause):

```
MATCH (n:`Procedure`) WHERE n.`name` = { `name_0` }  WITH n MATCH p=(n)-[*0..]->(m) RETURN p, ID(n) with params {name_0=WMS-1-B}
```

Did I miss something or is it a bug ?
Thanks.

Querying Neo4j 3.2 CE with the following dependencies:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j.driver</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-core</artifactId>         
       <version>2.1.3</version>         
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3</version>            
</dependency>
```

Comment: Have you relationships in both directions? That is: `(n)-->(m)` and `(n)<--(m)`.

Comment: Yes, I have something like that : `(:Procedure)-[:ROUTE_TO]->(:Task)-->(:Sink)<--(:Task)` and `(:Procedure)<-[:IS_PART_OF]-(:Task)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved with *queryForObject* method, for example:

```
T rvalue = ogmSession.queryForObject(this.classType, 
  "MATCH (n:`Procedure`) WHERE n.`name` = { `procedureName` } "+ 
  "WITH n MATCH p=(n)-[*0..10]->(m) RETURN p, ID(n)", Values.parameters("procedureName",identity).asMap());
```

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

The `Filter` API is not very clear on this.

The `setRelationshipDirection` (and `setRelationshipType`) relates to the filter MATCH on nested properties. The last MATCH will always be `p=(n)-[*0..]-(m)` to load all related nodes (but also see this [feature request](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/70)).

It is also set automatically based on the domain model. For example:

```
Filter filter = new Filter("itemName", "item1");
filter.setNestedPropertyName("items");
filter.setNestedPropertyType(Item.class);
session.loadAll(User.class, filter);
```

would result into

```
MATCH (n:`User`) MATCH (m0:`Item`) 
WHERE m0.`itemName` = { `items_itemName_0` } 
MATCH (n)-[:`HAS_ITEM`]-(m0) 
WITH n 
MATCH p=(n)-[*0..1]-(m) // provide depth to change 1 to something else
RETURN ....
```

The current API is there to support derived finders in Spring Data Neo4j and it might be easier and more readable to use custom query (which also allows you to [directly specify what to return and map](https://graphaware.com/neo4j/2016/04/06/mapping-query-entities-sdn.html) - see *Partially hydrating entities*).